# Completing an orthornomal sequence to obtain orthonormal basis in $ L^2[a,b] $

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

i am stumped with the following question : 
Suppose we have an orthonormal sequence $ \left \{ e_{n} , n \in \mathbb{N} \right.\left.  \right \} $  in $ L^2[a,b] $ can we add countable many functions such that we obtain an orthonormal basis 
[ $ L^2[a,b]=\overline{span\left \{ \left \{ e_{n},n \in \mathbb{N}\left.  \right \} \cup \left \{ x_{j},j \in \mathbb{N}\left.  \right \} \right. \right. \right.}
  $ ]
 for $ L^2[a,b] $ ?

Can we generalize for any separable Hilbert space ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with dense sequence $f_n$. Suppose you have an orthonormal sequence $e_n$. Let $U$ be the closure of the span of $e_n$ and $U^\perp$ the orthogonal complement of $U$. Let $p$ be the projection onto $U^\perp$.

Do the Gramm-schmidt procedure on $p(f_n)$ to get an orthnormal sequence that lies in $U^\perp$ (thus automatically orthogonal to $e_n$) and has the same (closure of) span as $p(f_n)$. Since the closure of $p(f_n)$ must be $U^\perp$ ($p$ is continuous) you found an orthonormal basis of $U^\perp$ and you started with one of $U$. Together they become a basis of $H$.

Comment: thanks @s.harp i got it , appreciate it a lot , i should have poked it a little more though .